# Check microphone permission status for windows platform in electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows, electron

In electron, There is API for check microphone permission status using [getMediaAccessStatus](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/system-preferences#systempreferencesaskformediaaccessmediatype-macos) but in windows platform, How can we check Is microphone is enable or not ?

Comment: Did you find the solution?